# why is the base64 encode java code doing this

Tags: java, base64, bitwise-operators

So I'm trying to understand base64 encoding better and I came across this implementation on wikipedia

```
private static String base64Encode(byte[] in)       {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer((in.length * 4) / 3);
        int b;
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i += 3)  {
            b = (in[i] & 0xFC) >> 2;
            out.append(codes.charAt(b));
            b = (in[i] & 0x03) << 4;
            if (i + 1 < in.length)      {
                b |= (in[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4;
                out.append(codes.charAt(b));
                b = (in[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2;
                if (i + 2 < in.length)  {
                    b |= (in[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6;
                    out.append(codes.charAt(b));
                    b = in[i + 2] & 0x3F;
                    out.append(codes.charAt(b));
                } else  {
                    out.append(codes.charAt(b));
                    out.append('=');
                }
            } else      {
                out.append(codes.charAt(b));
                out.append("==");
            }
        }

        return out.toString();
    }
```

And I'm following along and I get to the line:

```
b = (in[i] & 0xFC) >> 2;
```

and I don't get it...why would you `bitwise` and `252` to a number then shift it `right 2`...wouldn't it be the same if you just shifted the byte itself without doing the bitwise operation? example:

```
b = in[i] >> 2;
```

Say my `in[i]` was the `letter e`...represented as `101` or in `binary 01100101`.  If I shift that 2 to the right I get `011001` or `25`. If I bitwise & it I get

```
01100101
11111100
--------
01100100
```

but then the shift is going to chop off the last 2 anyway...so why bother doing it?

Can somebody clarify for me please.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IN `in[i] >> 2`, `in[i]` is converted to an `int` first. If it was a negative byte (with the high bit set) it will be converted to a negative int (with the now-highest 24 bits set as well).

In `(in[i] & 0xFC) >> 2`, `in[i]` is converted to an `int` as above, and then `& 0xFC` makes sure the extra bits are all reset to 0.

You're partially right, in that `(in[i] & 0xFF) >> 2` would give the same result. `& 0xFF` is a common way to convert a byte to a non-negative `int` in the range 0 to 255.

The only way to know for sure why the original developer used `0xFC`, and not `0xFF`, is to ask them - but I speculate that it's to make it more obvious which bits are being used.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer. I've never thought about this because I'm a C/++er mostly, and I default to using our novel feature, `unsigned`. :P This is very worth remembering in case I ever need to use signeds, though.

Comment: fwiw, sometimes in cases like this i would use `>> 2 & 63`. it depends whether i think the pre- or post-shift value is more significant to my understanding of the code.